# when click on an action button. the Swal is appearing at the top of the page instead of in the center

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

when click on an action button. the Swal is appearing at the top of the page instead of in the center.

do you have any idea.

it's in jquery,

```
.modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.swal2-popup {
  position: static;
}
```

i put this css . its not working

Comment: Could you share the HTML/Js as well so we can inspect well the code

Answer (score 0):

the question is resolved.

```
 body {
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 body.modal-open {
     overflow: visible;
     overflow-y: visible;
     overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```